# Post on friends wallpaper on Google plus from iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, google-plus

I have gone through https://developers.google.com/+/api/#calls but couldn't figured out the way to post on any friends wallpaper on Google plus.Please, give me some steps how to post on any friend wallpaper on Google plus.
Thanks,
Surya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google + Api is read-only, you can just share a link in the current api version

https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/share/#sharelink